# Taking user input to create a unique object

Tags: javascript, object, onclick, instance

I have been learning javascript for the past couple weeks and up until now I have been utilizing procedural programming to create my documents. I'm currently learning object-oriented programming, and while I know some java, it's been a while and I'm having trouble with these finicky objects. I want to take user input for a face value and suit of a card and use that data to instantiate an object from a constructor function. I know there are easier ways to do this but that would defeat the purpose of the lesson I'm trying to learn. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Card Constructor</title>
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Create a playing card!</h1>
    <script>
        function Card(){
           this.face=" ";
           this.suit=" ";
           this.info="You made a "+face+" of "+suit"!";
           this.showInfo=function(){
               alert(this.info);
           }
           this.setFace=function(newFace){
               this.face=newFace;  
           }
           this.setSuit=function(newSuit){
               this.suit=newSuit;
           }
        }
        function userCard(){
            var goodCard=new Card();
            goodCard.setFace=document.getElementById('faceInput').value=this.face; 
            goodCard.setSuit= document.getElementById('suitInput').value=this.suit;
            goodCard.showInfo();
            document.getElementById('faceInput').value=" ";
            document.getElementById('suitInput').value=" ";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center">
    <p>Please enter a face</p>
    <input type="text" id="faceInput" name="face" value=" "/>
    <p>And now a suit</p>
    <input type="text" id="suitInput" name="suit" value=" "/></br>
    </br><input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="userCard()"/>
</body>
```

Now, the problem is that my button doesn't work. If change my onClcik to onClick=alert('you clicked') I get a response. So I know I must have screwed something up in my script. Can anyone help a noob out?

Comment: change this: `this.info="You made a "+face+" of "+suit"!";` to `this.info="You made a "+this.face+" of "+this.suit"!";`

Comment: also where does your (`function Card(){`) scope close

Comment: First of all, you have a syntax error (as pointed out by @SheraliTurdiyev). This is the kind of error that you'd easily spot if you indented your code properly. Everything within `Card()` should be indented. Secondly, since `userCard()` is defined inside `Card()`, it's not available on the global scope, which is where you're trying to access it.

Comment: @Nico whoa man, pretty hostile. I know people around here probably don't like questions with syntax errors,  and I do admit that mine were silly and should not have been there, but this still doesn't resolve my issue. Still can't access it when I close my function at the correct spot.

Comment: Not sure what's so hostile in my reply @ChrisGomez - that certainly wasn't my intention. I was simply trying to point out the reason why it's not working.

Comment: @Nico I must have just read it in a tone you were not trying to elicit. Apologies mate thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone curious on how I ended up getting this to work, or if you have an assignment in your textbook that calls for creating objects with set methods and you're stuck, this is how I ended up doing mine. Note: I have two set methods that modify my one info method.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Card Constructor</title>
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Create a playing card!</h1>
    <script>
        function Card(face, suit){
            this.face="";
            this.suit="";
            this.info=face+" "+suit;
            this.setFace=function(newFace){
                this.face=newFace;  
            }
            this.setSuit=function(newSuit){
                this.suit=newSuit;
            }
            this.showInfo=function(){
                this.info="You made a "+this.face+" of "+this.suit+"!";
                alert(this.info);
        }
        }
        function userCard(){
            var goodCard=new Card();
            goodCard.setFace(document.getElementById('faceInput').value);
            goodCard.setSuit(document.getElementById('suitInput').value);
            goodCard.showInfo();
            document.getElementById('faceInput').value="";
            document.getElementById('suitInput').value="";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center">
    <p>Please enter a face</p>
    <input type="text" id="faceInput" name="face" value=""/>
    <p>And now a suit</p>
    <input type="text" id="suitInput" name="suit" value=""/></br>
    </br><input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="userCard()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your javascript code:

UPDATED:

1.There is your code has optimized.

Your `this.face` and `this.suit` is public variable, so there are `this.setFace` and `this.setSuit' unnecessary methods.

You just write `goodCard.face = ...` and `goodCard.suit = ...` instead of addressing to method

```
function Card(faceVal, suitVal) {
    this.face = faceVal;
    this.suit = suitVal;
    this.info = "";
    this.showInfo = function () {
        this.info = "You made a " + this.face + " of " + this.suit + "!";
        alert(this.info);
    }
}
function userCard() {
    var goodCard = new Card(document.getElementById('faceInput').value, document.getElementById('suitInput').value);
    goodCard.showInfo();
    document.getElementById('faceInput').value = "";
    document.getElementById('suitInput').value = "";
}
```

2.Also, I suggest other way to declare `Card` function.

There are private variables, getter/setter(also, you can use only setters or getters) as well as other public methods(like java `class`).

```
function Card(faceVal, suitVal) {
    //private variables
    var _face = faceVal || "",
        _suit = suitVal || "",
        _info = "";

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        //region <Getter & Setter>
        face: {
            get: function () {
                return _face;
            },
            set: function (val) {
                _face = val;
            },
            enumerable: true
        },
        suit: {
            get: function () {
                return _suit;
            },
            set: function (val) {
                _suit = val;
            },
            enumerable: true
        },
        info: {
            get: function () {
                return _info;
            },
            set: function (val) {
                _info = val;
            },
            enumerable: true
        }
    });

    //other public methods
    this.showInfo = function () {
        _info = "You made a " + _face + " of " + _suit + "!";
        alert(_info);//or alert(this.info)
    }
}

var goodCard = new Card();//you can define object outside without params

function userCard() {
    goodCard.face = document.getElementById('faceInput').value;
    goodCard.suit = document.getElementById('suitInput').value;
    goodCard.showInfo();
    document.getElementById('faceInput').value = "";
    document.getElementById('suitInput').value = "";
}
```

Comment: Tried your code but I'm still not getting a response from the button. Also, for this project, even though they aren't needed, I'd like to keep the set methods within the constructor. Otherwise I'll never learn to properly use objects.

Comment: @ChrisGomez. try this. i find  error:  `this.suit "!"`(there is without +). replace to `this.suit + "!"`

Comment: @ChrisGomez. you're welcome. I have updated my answer again. You can accept my answer.